# How to concatenate an uneven 2 dimensional array into a 1-d array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This works when I concatenate a 2-d array with rows of even lengths:

```
public static int[] concArr(int[][] arr){
        int[] oneD = new int[arr.length * arr.length];
          for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++)
          {
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j ++)
            {
                oneD[(i * arr.length) + j] = arr[i][j];
            }
          }
        return oneD;

    }
```

However, if an array is uneven, i.e:

```
{ {1, 2, 3},
  {4},
  null,
  {},
  {5,6}};
```

then the code will not work. How should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

1 . `for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j ++)`

Note `arr[i].length` instead of `arr.length`, you have to take into account the current row's length, since the rows are of unequal lengths.

2 . Instead of `oneD[(i * arr.length) + j]` use a variable to hold the current position in the result array; this variable is initialized with 0 and is incremented in the inner loop.

Comment: #1 makes sense, i should have thought about that.
Could you explain #2 more in detail - what do you mean by holding the current position? Do you mean creating a temp = arr[i][j]? (sorry, i am a newbie)

Comment: No, there is no need for a temporary. You need a variable to hold the current index in the `oneD` array, so you know where to copy `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: still can't figure it out.